# ul li list items checked and save it in Nightwatchjs

Tags: testing, mocha.js, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to build a News site and I need to do some testing with NightwatchJS in the process.

I want to make something like like an RSS feed and when testing the information should be sent to the API.

**Here is what I tried:**

```
browser.elements('css selector','ul#feed-list', function (result) {
  els = result.value;
  var jsonString = "";

  els.forEach(function(el,j,elz) {
    browser.elementIdText(el.ELEMENT, function(text) {
      jsonString += text;
    });
    console.log(jsonString);
});
```

Here the sample code to the from the site:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div1>
    <div2>
    <div3>
    <div class="tab-active">
      <div class="full-content">
        <ul class="media-list" id="list-feed">
          <li class="block blog _feedBlog blog-feed" id="blog-******">
            <div class="news-body">
            <div class="author">
            <div class="title">
            <div class="news-text">
```

where:

- `******` is the news article ID;
- `tab-active` is the whole tab with news
- `full-content` represents the whole feed under `tab-active`

So, basically I need to read the last 10 items of the `ul` and if they are not already present, send them via an API call.

I need `title`, `author` and `news-text` to be stored in variables so I can send them and if something is missing, or if the text is small sized on the news, I want to be notified.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Niko! Can you confirm that this is correct? (*So, basically I need to read the last 10 items of the `ul` and if they are not already present, send them via an API call.*) I had to edit your question cause the formatting was kinda off...

Comment: @iamdanchiv thanks!